# Setting up the default browser (IE, Homepage)

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer, windows-10, registry, command-prompt

Those are actually two different questions but still they are connected. I am trying to make a script to automate the installation of company PCs for new employees.
An old script used to work fine but as of the 1703 update (or some time prior. No-one really knows), the changes no longer do their job and I cannot seem to find a fix.
The task:

1. Change the default browser from Edge to Internet Explorer
2. Set the IE homepage to "https://www.google.com"

Concerning the first problem: I have tried changing the Registry entries at 
HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\http(s)\UserChoice\ 
No luck there. I have also tried exporting and the setting using DISM but importing them back has proven to be beyond my capabilities (Basically, I ran into this problem: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d5fad871-8f5e-4c74-abaf-627809f8844b/ I cannot programatically change the settings for an existing user)

When facing the second problem, I tried searching the registry for the default site "go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p?LinkId=..." and changing the values. At one startup (After I modiffied the registry key 
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main 
 value "Start Page"), IE displayed a prompt to the user informing them that an external appliation wishes to change the homepage but no change actually occured. And this only happened once (even after I changed the value again to a different site)

A preferred method would be using Powershell but after googling and ripping my hair out for two days straight, I am open to any suggestions. If it makes any difference, it's a 64-bit Windows 10 Pro

Comment: This should be done in Group Policy. Is there a reason it isnt?

Comment: Do you plan on creating a login script (scheduled task or GPO) to enforce the changes on users?  If GPO, you may as well take the above's comment suggestion.

Comment: No login script and no enforcing. Just "factory setting". The main reason for not using GP was that so far I never have used it. I will try the GP. Thank you for the suggestion.